# Constraint on type pairs

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-level-computation

I'm trying to define a typeclass that each element of a type pair satisfies a constraint:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableSuperClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data a ::: b = a ::: b

class    (c1 x, c2 y) => CP c1 c2 (k :: x ::: y)
instance (c1 x, c2 y) => CP c1 c2 (k :: x ::: y)
```

However this is not exaclty what i need because CP is of the wrong kind

```
:kind CP
CP :: (* -> Constraint) -> (* -> Constraint) -> (x ::: y) -> Constraint
```

How can I make `c1` and `c2` arguments be of more general kind `k -> Constraint`?

Comment: Let's say i have a type
`data Foo t where Foo :: Proxy s -> Proxy n -> Foo (s '::: n)`

then i want to be able to say
`CP KnownSymbol KnownNat t => Foo t`

Comment: GHC does noot accept `class (c1 x, c2 y) => CP c1 c2 (x '::: y)`

Comment: @Ryba In a `class` declaration, you must use type variables not concrete types, although you can specify their kinds. Something like this works `class CP (c1 :: k -> Constraint) (c2 :: k -> Constraint) (z :: k ::: k)`. I had to remove the preconditions from the class however, because `x` and `y` aren't mentioned now.

Comment: @danidiaz well, but I guess that precondition is really what the goal of this all is, no? Sth. equivalent to `data CPWit c₁ c₂ z where CPWit :: (c₁ x, c₂ y)=>CPWit c₁ c₂ (x':::y)` and `class CP c₁ c₂ z where cpWit::CPWit c₁ c₂ z` but with the `(c₁ x, c₂ y)` context in a superclass instead of a GADT so that no explicit value unwrapping is needed.

Comment: @danidiaz Without precondition i can't split `Foo` and recover individual constraints

Comment: @Ryba Perhaps you could define a pair of type families `Fst` and `Snd` which extracted the first and second component types out of a `(z :: k ::: k)` type. Then you could refer to them in the preconditions, like `class (c1 (Fst z), c2 (Snd z)) => ...`. Not sure if that would work though.

Comment: I did try that. Technically it works, but once i started working with it i got errors  - `Fst (x '::: y) ~ x` cant always be inferred. I probably could make it compile by providing some helper functions (like ` Proxy (x '::: y) -> Proxy (Fst (x '::: y)) but this is a bit impractical

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying the constraints to the types of the elements of the pair. In order to apply it to the elements, do this:

```
class (k ~ (Fst k '::: Snd k), c1 (Fst k), c2 (Snd k)) => CP c1 c2 (k :: x ::: y) where
    type Fst k :: x
    type Snd k :: y
instance (c1 a, c2 b) => CP c1 c2 ((a :: x) '::: (b :: y)) where
    type Fst (a '::: b) = a
    type Snd (a '::: b) = b
```

The class definition says that each `k :: x ::: y` has a `Fst k :: x` and a `Snd k :: y` (the elements), and in order for `CP c1 c2 k` to hold, the elements must satisfy their respective constraints and `k` must indeed be the pair of its elements. The instance declaration then restates that, and also defines `Fst` and `Snd`. Now

```
ghci> :k CP
CP :: forall x y.
      (x -> Constraint) -> (y -> Constraint) -> (x ::: y) -> Constraint
```

And e.g. this works:

```
type MyPair = String '::: Just False -- :: Type ::: Maybe Bool
class m ~ Just (FromJust m) => IsJust (m :: Maybe k) where type FromJust m :: k
instance IsJust (Just x) where type FromJust (Just x) = x

test :: ()
test = () :: CP Show IsJust MyPair => ()
```

Comment: Better to use independent type families than associated types here.